# inserting EQUALOP error in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to swap elements in a list in ML. My swap function returns the error inserting EQUALOP.

```
fun swap(n:int, i:int, deck:card list) =
                local
                    val card1_removed = nth(deck,i)
                    val card2_removed = nth(deck,n)
                in
                    val deck = remove(deck,i)
                    val deck = remove(deck,n)
                    val deck = insert_at(deck,n,card1_removed)
                    val deck = insert_at(deck,i,card2_removed)
                    print_cards(deck);
                end;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code.

First off you cant have a local declaration inside a function definition like that. The body of a function must be an expression, and `local ... in .. end` is a declaration. In this case you have to use `let ... in .. end`, which is an expression.

Note that you can't have value declarations in the `in ... end` part of a let-expression though. Here you will have to move all the value declarations up in the `let ... in` part.

To be a bit more clear the form of let and local is:

```
<atexp> ::= let <dec> in <exp_1> ; ... ; <exp_n> end 

<dec>   ::= local <dec_1> in <dec_2> end
```

Thus, normally local is used like this

```
local 
  fun foo ...
  val ....
in 
  fun swap ...
end
```

where let is used like this

```
fun swap ...
  let
    val ...
  in
    ..
  end
```